# Can't add a file to fetch POST request

Tags: javascript, postman, fetch-api

I have a request that succeeds in postman, but just fails when I call it from my JS code. The requests are similar in the Chrome dev tools, and I suspect that I'm just not adding the file correctly. This is how the file is added in the postman:

[image]

This is my JS code:

```
let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', event.target.files[0]);
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/file/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JWT
            },
            body:formData
        }).then(response => console.log(response));
```

This code is executed when the file of an input (type='file') changes. When I console.log the event.target.files[0], I get:
[image]

Am I adding the file wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
> ```

`multipart/form-data` needs a parameter to describe the boundry marker.

`fetch` will generate an appropriate `Content-Type` header automatically, but you are overriding it and replacing it with a broken one.

Remove that line.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Learning something new every day. The request now works, but it seems like I'm not getting a response back. In Postman, however, I am. Any obvious reason for this?

Comment: Any way I can manually add this header WITH the boundary marker?

Comment: @gfels — Only if you want to replace `FormData` with your own version so you can find out what the boundary marker is.